# MongoDB Atlas Trigger Function: Context Services Get ('my cluster') Doesn't have a db defined

Tags: mongodb, triggers, mongodb-atlas

I'm setting up a database trigger function to run after an insert/update. The goal was to auto compute the `rating` field of a product based on changes of the nested reviews array's ratings.

[image: Trigger Function]
[image: Console log]

The part I'm getting stuck at is getting the `products` initialized. As you can see from the 2nd picture with the `logs`, the context.services.get() call returns an object with just `version` in it. And so I can't chain a .db() nor a later .collection() on it. I haven't found anything useful elsewhere. Help!

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct cluster name?

Use the same name as the linked data source, you should see it above the function code editor in: Edit Trigger -> Trigger details -> Link Data Source(s)

Comment: Yes I'm sure. The exact text that shows on that very page is what I copied.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why is the db connection commented out? You're trying to print the service which is why you're getting only the version.

Second, you have to use `async` when make db queries. Here's an example:

```js
exports = async function(changeEvent) {
  const collection = context.services.get("ClusterName").db("db_name").collection("collection_name");
  const item = await collection.findOne();
};
```

Comment: Adding async does not help when context.services.get("ClusterName") already does not have the attribute "db"